# VS Code not opening folders

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to open a folder in VScode, the files dont appear yet the folder name appears on top
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLNRI.png)

This seems like a bug that didn't happen before.

Ive tried reinstalling, removing extensions, opening from terminal with code., trying with different folders, updating everything but still not working. Im left stranded without the ability to work. Any ideas?